# How to maintain backwards compatibility for Three.js JSON files exported from Blender

Tags: three.js, blender

We have over a thousands models that were exported using Three.js Blender exporter r69, with the option to "Flip YZ" un-checked. There's also code in the app that flips them the right way up, so they are the same between Blender and the app.

We've upgraded the exporter since (r76+) - the option to Flip XY is now removed, and the new models on their side. Obvious solution is to remove the app code that was flipping them back in our app in the first place, which works, but breaks compatibility with all models previously exported with r69.

Here are some methods I thought about/tried but to no avail:

- I can check the version of the JSON file and flip only ones exported with the old exporter. JSON does have a "metadata" field, except, this is not exposed to the result of JSONLoader.load(). No go.
- Reverse-Engineer the exporter diff between the versions and see if I can write a script to update the thousands of models from 69 to 76.
- Import all of the original models and re-export as r76. This is a lot of work for thousands of models, and since we can't import JSON, we need to have the original Blend files, which is not always true.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Is there an approach I am missing? Is there a better way to migrate many models from one exporter JSON version to another?

Answer (score 1):

The change was [mentioned a bit ago](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5841), but I can't find it documented anywhere else. The shift, as you found is now automatic. The code appears to define the up axis at line 366 in [object.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/api/object.py) I'd test, but I don't use Blender. Swap the values and see what happens.

My answer is that your use case makes a compelling reason to put the option back in. I suggest modifying the object.py yourself for your needs, submitting it as a pull request, and opening an issue to allow a discussion on a fix @repsac